How to change background-color of QPushButton in PyQtDarkTheme
I'm trying to change the background-color of my QPushButtons in PyQtDarkTheme, but it just doesn't work.

My real project I'm working on:

I've tried it like this, changing the text-color or everything else works fine, but not the background.
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import sys
import qdarktheme

qss = """
QPushButton {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    }
"""

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        
        self.button = QPushButton("Press Me")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qdarktheme.setup_theme(additional_qss=qss)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()

What am I doing wrong?
I know I could change every button individually with
button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: red}')

but that causes a bunch of other problems I want to avoid.
